# How can I tell if my computer went to sleep?

Tags: windows-7, power-management

I'm trying to work out if my computer has actually fallen asleep, I have set it to fall asleep, but it restarts so quickly, I cannot tell if it was actually having zzzzs or not.

What logs are there to tell me when and if my PC fell asleep?

Answer (score 30):

Oh I found it, only minutes after posting this.

1. Crack open event viewer (eventvwr from the command line)
2. event ID 42 in System log from source Kernel-Power as the sleeping event
3. event ID 1 in System log from source Power-Troubleshooter for computer's awakening

The last and first logs entries upon sleeping/waking up

This command (from the commandline) also lets you know what is keeping your PC awake (if anything)

```
 powercfg -requests
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I noticed my laptop went to sleep last night against my will, having left it on for OneDrive syncing. (The default Windows 10 settings set it to sleep after so many minutes if it's on battery or even plugged in.) I see event ID 42 and 107 showing it went to sleep (42) and resumed from sleep (107). Which is interesting why the last log of when it went to sleep is resuming from sleep. Perhaps the time stamp is incorrect when it wakes up. Additionally, I noticed the laptop woke up 3 hours later on its own: There's an even ID 1, 131, 1, 18, 32, 42, 107. Curious why?